# Find a lower bound for the probability that X lies between 8 and 12, using Chebyshev’s Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose a number X is chosen at random from [0, 20] with uniform
probability. Find a lower bound for the probability that X lies between
8 and 12, using Chebyshev’s Inequality

I tried to take the integral first in order to find the mean, $$\int_{0}^{20}\frac x {20}\,dx,$$ and eventually got 10 as the mean, then I tried to find the variance by doing another integration, and got 100/3, later when I used chebychevs inequality, I still couldnt find the solution.

Comment: Have you written down Chebyshev inequality in this case ? Besides, finding 10 for the mean does not truly necessitates an integral...

Comment: One thing more : can you, more or less, guess what the result will be for a so simple density ?